# Segmentation Fault. For loop from 0 to 987654321

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<987654321; i++) {
    printf("\t%d\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the program shows **Segmentation Fault**.

What can I do to solve this problem? I searched on Google but I can't find anything related to this kind of problem.

Thank you all.

PS: I am a beginner of C.

EDIT:

I am using a 64 bit computer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96051/discussion-on-question-by-mm-pp-segmentation-fault-for-loop-from-0-to-987654321).